# Install RAM in the server HP ProLiant DL180 G6

Tags: windows, memory, hp, serverspec

I have server HP ProLiant DL180 G6 with Windows Server 2008 x64. It has 64 GB of RAM installed. Only 32 are used. Changed the location of the RAM for this information https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3884342&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c01702229
But it did not help. RAM samsung 16gb 4rx4 pc3 8500r x 4

Comment: When you reboot the server, how much RAM does the BIOS screen show (before the O/S boots)?

Comment: @Binarus shows 64 gb

Comment: So we know it is a problem with Windows Server 2008 and not with the server hardware. I have already suspected this. Please have a look at my answer (which will be visible in about 10 minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of `Windows Server 2008 Standard` and even `Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard`. Please have a look at the following page:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#physical-memory-limits-windows-server-2008-r2

Basically, `Windows Server 2008` is limited to use only 32 GB of memory, unless you are running one of the (expensive) HPC / Cluster / Enterprise versions. You can't do anything about it, except upgrading to one of these versions (if you urgently need 2008) or to a later version, for example `Windows Server 2012 Standard`, which is allowed to use 4 TB of RAM, and which should not cost much more than `Windows Server 2008 (R2) Standard`.